# Cancellable threading.Timer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a method that counts down to a given time and unless a restart command is given, it will execute the task. But I don't think Python `threading.Timer` class allows for timer to be cancelable.

```
import threading

def countdown(action):
    def printText():
        print 'hello!'

    t = threading.Timer(5.0, printText)
    if (action == 'reset'):
        t.cancel()

    t.start()
```

I know the above code is wrong somehow. Would appreciate some kind guidance over here.

Answer (score 41):

You would call the cancel method after you start the timer:

```
import time
import threading

def hello():
    print "hello, world"
    time.sleep(2)

t = threading.Timer(3.0, hello)
t.start()
var = 'something'
if var == 'something':
    t.cancel()
```

You might consider using a while-loop on a [*Thread*](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#threading.Thread), instead of using a *Timer*.
Here is an example appropriated from Nikolaus Gradwohl's [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4153314/1217270) to another question:

```
import threading
import time

class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.count = 10

    def run(self):
        while self.count > 0 and not self.event.is_set():
            print self.count
            self.count -= 1
            self.event.wait(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

tmr = TimerClass()
tmr.start()

time.sleep(3)

tmr.stop()
```

Comment: Please explain why you think a timed while loop is a better idea than the threaded timer.

Comment: @WesModes I offered an alternative that prints the count down.

Comment: Works for me. Although i used  while not self.event.wait(1)  to execute something every second instead of a count variable

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Do you want to write something like in this example?

```
>>> import threading
>>> t = None
>>> 
>>> def sayHello():
...     global t
...     print "Hello!"
...     t = threading.Timer(0.5, sayHello)
...     t.start()
... 
>>> sayHello()
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
Hello!
>>> t.cancel()
>>>
```

Comment: It's _almost_ good. It would be *good* if your program didn't terminate immediately, with a single "Hello" and no delay at all! :)  You have to incorporate `t.cancel()` into the `sayHello()` function based on some condtion, e.g. `if counter == 10: t.cancel()`. It would then have a meaning.

Comment: Sorry. It wouldn't be good even then. If you add any code after calling `sayHello(0)`, it will be executed before the timer test finishes! (Try it yourself, by adding e.g. `print "Done"`at the end of your code.)

Answer (score 8):

The `threading.Timer` class *does* have a `cancel` method, and although it won't cancel the *thread*, it will stop the timer from actually firing. What actually happens is that the `cancel` method sets a `threading.Event`, and the thread actually executing the `threading.Timer` will check that event after it's done waiting and before it actually executes the callback.

That said, timers are usually implemented *without* using a separate thread for each one. The best way to do it depends on what your program is actually doing (while waiting for this timer), but anything with an event loop, like GUI and network frameworks, all have ways to request a timer that is hooked into the eventloop.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if best option but for me is woking like this:
t = timer_mgr(.....) append to list "timers.append(t)" and then after all created you can call:

```
for tm in timers:#threading.enumerate():
     print "********", tm.cancel()
```

my timer_mgr() class is this:

```
class timer_mgr():
def __init__(self, st, t, hFunction, id, name):
    self.is_list = (type(st) is list)
    self.st = st
    self.t = t
    self.id = id
    self.hFunction = hFunction      
    self.thread = threading.Timer(t, self.handle_function, [id])
    self.thread.name = name

def handle_function(self, id):
    if self.is_list:
        print "run_at_time:", datetime.now()
        self.hFunction(id)
        dt = schedule_fixed_times(datetime.now(), self.st)
        print "next:", dt
        self.t = (dt-datetime.now()).total_seconds()
    else:
        self.t = self.st        
        print "run_every", self.t, datetime.now()
        self.hFunction(id)

    self.thread = threading.Timer(self.t, self.handle_function, [id])
    self.thread.start()             

def start(self):
    self.thread.start()

def cancel(self):
    self.thread.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by above post.
Cancelable and Resetting Timer in Python. It uses thread.
Features: Start, Stop, Restart, callback function.
Input: Timeout, sleep_chunk values, and callback_function.
Can use or inherit this class in any other program. Can also pass arguments to the callback function.
Timer should respond in middle also. Not just after completion of full sleep time. So instead of using one full sleep, using small chunks of sleep and kept checking event object in loop.

```
import threading
import time

class TimerThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, timeout=3, sleep_chunk=0.25, callback=None, *args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.timeout = timeout
        self.sleep_chunk = sleep_chunk
        if callback == None:
            self.callback = None
        else:
            self.callback = callback
        self.callback_args = args

        self.terminate_event = threading.Event()
        self.start_event = threading.Event()
        self.reset_event = threading.Event()
        self.count = self.timeout/self.sleep_chunk

    def run(self):
        while not self.terminate_event.is_set():
            while self.count > 0 and self.start_event.is_set():
                # print self.count
                # time.sleep(self.sleep_chunk)
                # if self.reset_event.is_set():
                if self.reset_event.wait(self.sleep_chunk):  # wait for a small chunk of timeout
                    self.reset_event.clear()
                    self.count = self.timeout/self.sleep_chunk  # reset
                self.count -= 1
            if self.count <= 0:
                self.start_event.clear()
                #print 'timeout. calling function...'
                self.callback(*self.callback_args)
                self.count = self.timeout/self.sleep_chunk  #reset

    def start_timer(self):
        self.start_event.set()

    def stop_timer(self):
        self.start_event.clear()
        self.count = self.timeout / self.sleep_chunk  # reset

    def restart_timer(self):
        # reset only if timer is running. otherwise start timer afresh
        if self.start_event.is_set():
            self.reset_event.set()
        else:
            self.start_event.set()

    def terminate(self):
        self.terminate_event.set()

#=================================================================
def my_callback_function():
    print 'timeout, do this...'

timeout = 6  # sec
sleep_chunk = .25  # sec

tmr = TimerThread(timeout, sleep_chunk, my_callback_function)
tmr.start()

quit = '0'
while True:
    quit = raw_input("Proceed or quit: ")
    if quit == 'q':
        tmr.terminate()
        tmr.join()
        break
    tmr.start_timer()
    if raw_input("Stop ? : ") == 's':
        tmr.stop_timer()
    if raw_input("Restart ? : ") == 'r':
        tmr.restart_timer()
```

Comment: if I have class `TimerThread` and class `Application`, and my callback function is in Application, how do I call TimerThread and set callback on self? I have tried your code, but it never hit callback.