# Do something every n seconds without while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, freeze, blender

Well, I'm trying to write an add-on for Blender and I need to do something every n seconds, but, I can't use a while loop, because it freezes Blender!!! What do I do?

Comment: I do not know python well. but cant you do with a Timer and a Handler for that !

Comment: Why was this question closed? It is perfectly valid if you are using Blender, and is directly related to a programming language.

Comment: That's how Stack Overflow works... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Strange errors using ‘threading’ module](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_62_2/info_gotcha.html#strange-errors-using-threading-module) of the Blender API documentation:

> Python threading with Blender only works properly when the threads finish up before the script does. By using threading.join() for example.
>
> **Note**: Pythons threads only allow co-currency and won’t speed up your scripts on multi-processor systems, the subprocess and multiprocess modules can be used with blender and make use of multiple CPU’s too.

```
from threading import Thread, Event

class Repeat(Thread):
    def __init__(self,delay,function,*args,**kwargs):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.abort = Event()
        self.delay = delay
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.function = function
    def stop(self):
        self.abort.set()
    def run(self):
        while not self.abort.isSet():
            self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
            self.abort.wait(self.delay)
```

Example:

```
from time import sleep
def do_work(foo):
    print "busy", foo
r = Repeat(1,do_work,3.14) # execute do_work(3.14) every second
r.start() # start the thread
sleep(5)  # let this demo run for 5s
r.stop()  # tell the thread to wake up and stop
r.join()  # don't forget to .join() before your script ends
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from threading import Timer

def doSomeThings():
    print "Things are being done"

t = Timer(5.0, doSomeThings)  # every 5 seconds
t.start()
```

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be done continuously every n seconds...

Comment: Worth mentioning how you stop this?

Comment: @Antoni4040 replace `5.0` with `n`.

Comment: @hayden - you can call the `cancel` method of the timer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812344/cancellable-threading-timer-in-python

Comment: Well, this just prints it after 5 seconds but not continuously...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs, `time.sleep` or `threading.Timer` might do the job.

If you need a more comprehensive scheduler, my favourite version is the recipe found at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496800-event-scheduling-threadingtimer/:

```
import thread
import threading

class Operation(threading._Timer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading._Timer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.finished.clear()
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.isSet():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            else:
                return
            self.finished.set()

class Manager(object):

    ops = []

    def add_operation(self, operation, interval, args=[], kwargs={}):
        op = Operation(interval, operation, args, kwargs)
        self.ops.append(op)
        thread.start_new_thread(op.run, ())

    def stop(self):
        for op in self.ops:
            op.cancel()

class LockPrint(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
    def lprint(self, value):
        with self.lock:
            print value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    import datetime

    lp = LockPrint()

    def hello1():
        lp.lprint('{}\thello1!'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    def hello2():
        lp.lprint('{}\thello2!'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
    def hello3_blocking(): # this is bad, so don't do it in real code ;)
        lp.lprint('{}\thello3_blocking starting... '.format(
            datetime.datetime.now()
        )),
        t = time.time() # get a timestamp
        x = 0
        while time.time() - t < 3: # iterate in a blocking loop for 3 secs
            x += 1
        lp.lprint('{}\thello3_blocking complete! ({} iterations)'.format(
            datetime.datetime.now(), x
        ))



    timer = Manager()
    timer.add_operation(hello1, 1)
    timer.add_operation(hello2, 2)
    timer.add_operation(hello3_blocking, 2)

    t0 = time.time()
    while time.time() - t0 < 10:
        time.sleep(0.1)
    # turn off everything and exit...
    timer.stop()
```

This is generally time-safe, in the sense that since every operation is executed under a thread, the main thread can still switch out of blocking sections in individual operation threads and maintain the schedules on the other operations (assuming your functions don't raise any exceptions all the way to the interpreter, breaking the main scheduler thread...)

I'm not sure how this will behave with blender, but it works well in a non-blocking mode with other environments I've used (specifically, tornado based servers.)

Answer (score -1):

```
import threading

def hello():
   print "hello, world"
   t = threading.Timer(30.0, hello)
   t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

I am not very good with python and havent tried this. See if this helps you :)

Comment: @hayden that's not true. Adding `threading.activeCount()` to the `print` statement, you can see there are at most 3 running threads (2 before `t.start()` and 3 after): the parent (previous `hello`), the one currently executing (current `hello`), and the one being spawned (`t.start`). The problem with this code is that you can't break out of the timer loop, forcing the user to terminate the process externally.

Comment: @Nisan.H that is still quite a problem...

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be very difficult to add a condition check on some thread-safe variable at each step to determine whether the loop should stop. It's a very basic timer, and I would generally avoid using it in that particular form for anything more complex than a single-function infinite loop, but it does work.  Of course, one might just as well use `time.sleep(x)` in a `while True:...` loop without the threading, since it doesn't add any benefit in this example.

Comment: Also, starting it with an external `threading.Timer(x, hello)` call would allow you to continue running the main worker thread (e.g. other parts of your script) separate from the recursively spawning/dying timer thread. You just wouldn't have any control over that thread until you exit the main worker thread.