# timer that calls every n milliseconds a function without .after or threading

Tags: python, timer, tkinter

I need a timer that calls a function every n milliseconds.
This should not be in a endloss loop (while true) or something like that

```
import threading

def printit():
   threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
   print "Hello, World!"
```

Or

```
def printit():
    root.after(100,printit())
```

As I have a GUI that should be able to interact. So that I can stop the timer.

Some ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this link you should find help there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812344/cancellable-threading-timer-in-python

Comment: why "without .after"? That's exactly what you should use in tkinter. With `after`, you can interact during the periods when the function isn't running, and you can certainly stop the loop at any time.

Comment: You are right. But the function that the timer shall call is a more or less real-time data plot function. So the timer should call it really fast. So there is no time for the user to interrupt it. Is there another way to stop a function during the process?

Comment: How long does the "real-time data plot function" take? Does it run in just a few hundred milliseconds or less?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question explictly says not to use `after`, but that's exactly how you do it with tkinter (assuming your function doesn't take more than a couple hundred ms to complete). For example:

```
def printit():
    if not stopFlag:
        root.after(100,printit)
...
def stop():
    global stopFlag
    stopFlag = False
...
printit()
```

The above will cause `printit` to be called every 100ms until some other piece of code sets `stopFlag` to `False`.

Note: this will not work very well if `printit` takes more than 100ms. If the function takes two much time, your only choices are to move the function into a thread, or move it to another process. If `printit` takes 100ms or less, the above code is sufficient to keep your UI responsive.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. 
Fortunately the print functions takes 100ms or less.

Answer (score 0):

From [Python Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html)

```
from threading import Timer
def hello():
    print "hello, world"

t = Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start() # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed`
```

Comment: Ok. How can I check if a stopflag is true or not to stop the timer? If I run it in a while loop my tkinter GUI stopbutton does not react.

Comment: Do you want to stop the `timer`?
You can use `t.cancel()` to stop