# Python: How to avoid a 'wait' in a thread stopping the flow of program?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, wait, python-multithreading

In the example below the timer will keep printing `hello world` every 5 seconds and never stop, how can I allow the timer thread to function as a timer (printing 'hello world') but also not stop the progression of the program?

```
import threading
class Timer_Class(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.running = True
    def run(self, timer_wait, my_fun, print_text):
        while self.running:
            my_fun(print_text)
            self.event.wait(timer_wait)

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False




def print_something(text_to_print):
    print(text_to_print)


timr = Timer_Class()
timr.run(5, print_something, 'hello world')
timr.stop() # How can I get the program to execute this line?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
while self.running:
```

Your code contains a loop that will keep looping until the loop condition `self.running` is *somehow* changed to `False`.

If you want to not loop, I suggest you remove that **looping** part in your code.

And then: you are **not** calling `start()` on your thread object. Therefore you *current* code does *everything* on the main thread. In order to really utilize more than one thread you have to call `timr.start()` at some point!

So the *real* answer here: step back learn how multi-threading works in Python (for example have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905965/creating-threads-in-python)). It seems that you have heard some concepts and go trial/error. And that is a very inefficient strategy.

Comment: Hi the code above was adopted by a stackoveflow question https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812806/157416
Which seems to have a high up vote. I know the code is creating a loop which is the desired result however by threading I am trying disconnect the looping from the main thread. The OP is asking for how to achieve this. I will have a look at the link you provided. But your answer is just describing what I already know so far. Thank you

Comment: And you missed the **start()** call which is present in the example code. so from that point of view: simply step back and consider if my answer solved your issue, if so, kindly think about accepting. Or letting me know what is missing for you to get there.

Comment: Ok I will be looking into the start() call thank you.

Comment: The start() seems to make it so that the thread runs in parallel, can I ask why calling run() directly doesn't have the same outcome?

Comment: Simple: because that is how **threads** work. A thread is the abstraction allow you to **start** a parallel thread of execution. And the abstraction requires you to **start** that thread in order to well, get it started. This is like asking "why do I have to turn the keys to start the engine - why is just sitting in the car not good enough?"