# Python Threading timer not working across suspend

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a program that syncs with a server every 60 seconds.  The code I'm using to do that looks like:

```
threading.Timer(60, self.sync, [""]).start()
```

Pretty simple, and works great.  The issue is if I decide to suspend the machine for a period of time and then come back, it doesn't work anymore.  It's as if the timer stopped working.  I suspect this has to do with the gap in real-world time as perceived by the timer, but I'm not sure how to make it work.

The app I'm making is targeted at OSX, so maybe there is a system-level timer that I could have access to?

Comment: This probably just does the same thing under-the-hood, but you could try the method here instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4153314/429982

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398661/schedule-a-repeating-event-in-python-3

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work any better, but you could give it a try:

```
import time

def call_sync(freq, meth):
    cur_time = time.time()
    while True:
        while (time.time() - cur_time) < freq:
            yield None
        meth()
        cur_time = time.time()


def sync():
    print("synced")

def main():
    timer = call_sync(60, sync)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        next(timer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```