# Python thread can not be cancelled

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a python thread which should display a message every second, while the rest of the script continues running. But the `timer.cancel` function does not work, as it still keeps running even after the main loop have been terminated:

```
from threading import *
import time
import sys

a = 0

def x():
    while(True):
        global a
        print
        print 'Beep', a
        print
        time.sleep(1)   # wait 1 second      

t = Timer(1.0, x)       # create thread
t.start()               # start thread

while True:
    a = a + 1
    print a
    time.sleep(0.1)

    if a > 30:    
        t.cancel()
    if a > 50:
        sys.exit()
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The [`threading.Timer`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0792a0ad7f22/Lib/threading.py#l1049) class has one `cancel` method, but it **won't** cancel the thread, it will stop the timer from actually firing. Actually, the `cancel` method sets a `threading.Event`, and thread actually executing the `threading.Timer` will check that event after it's done waiting and before it actually executes the callback.

Here is maybe one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4153314/3011380) to meet your requirement.

```
import threading
import time
import sys

a = 0

class TimerClass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.event.is_set():
            global a
            print
            print 'Beep', a
            print
            self.event.wait(1)

    def stop(self):
        self.event.set()

t = TimerClass()
t.start()

while True:
    a = a + 1
    print a
    time.sleep(0.1)

    if a > 30:    
        t.stop()
    if a > 50:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your threading code as much i can get is your beep part is executing with timer set to 1-sec even when your a=a+1 part is stop so simply what u can do is add a condition in beep part as:

```
    time.sleep(1)         
    if a>50:
      sys.exit()
```

This will stop the execution of thread and you will get your desired result
This is simplest thing that u can do or else follow the zangw method() which works well for run and stop of thread